# Will a self service check-in machine know that I have connecting flights and transfer my luggage?

Tags: germany, check-in, connecting-flights, lufthansa

I have a connecting flight from Hamburg through Frankfurt with Lufthansa. I have only 45 minutes to catch the other flight. Usually when the check-in is done in person, I can say that I have a connecting flight and that I would like my luggage to be transferred without collecting it. But I know that in Hamburg the check-in is done using a machine (and I am not sure if there is the option of using the traditional way). I am worried that I will not be able to specify to the machine that I have a connecting flight and that would need to re-check my luggage, as 45 minutes would not be enough in this case. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are your flights on a single booking? Usually check-in kiosk will spontaneously print baggage tags that route bags through to your final destination according to the booking.

Comment: It is actually rather hard to get your luggage _not_ checked through, because the airline would assume you use 'hidden city ticketing'. So don't worry.

Comment: The handling of luggage in connecting flights is frankly magical, it works far better than I would have expected. Airline/airport staff really know what they are doing.
I was really kinda surprised the first time I took a flight with 3 legs, the last of which being a smaller domestic flight (with a partner airline) to a remoteish airport, and yet still my luggage arrived without issue.

Comment: The check-in kiosk isn't mandatory, it is just an alternative. You always have the option to go to the desk and do it the usual way. Companies offer the kiosk because it's cheaper, and you might want to choose it because it can be faster, but you don't have to.

Comment: @FabioTurati I was checking in at Frankfurt Airport with Lufthansa about 4 weeks ago and I can say from experience: usage of the check in kiosk is in fact mandatory (at least in Frankfurt). If you tried to get to the counter without going to the kiosk first, a not very friendly lady would tell you to back off and go to the kiosk. (trust me I tried)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's a single booking, your bags will automatically checked through to your final destination. You should be getting the boarding passes of both flights in Hamburg from the Kiosk and the baggage tag should show your final destination.

See https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Checking-in-baggage for baggage drop off instruction in Hamburg

More info on using a check in machine: https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/check-in-machine. You need proper ID for the process.

Answer (score 13):

If your flights are on a single booking, check-in kiosks will generally always print baggage tags that route your bags through to your final destination.

You can check before you attach the tag to your bag that it shows the airport code for your final destination in large letters. If it doesn't, seek help to have it retagged from the airline staff that are always present near the kiosk to help travelers.

Comment: "generally always"

Comment: @FooBar It makes sense to me if the intended meaning is that most checkin kiosks are configured to always print baggage tags that route to the final destination.